# printing out date in uniform order and a counter

Tags: python

I have been doing these for hours! please help! New to python

example 1990 for input year
and 2000 for end year.

basically i want the output to be

> the years are 1992 1996 2000
>
> there are 3 counts

I thought of converting them to a list and using len() but i do not know how

```
#inputs
year = int(raw_input("Input year: "))
endyear = int(raw_input("Input end year:"))

print "The number of leap years are "

counter = 0
for x in range(year,endyear+1):
    
    if x % 4 == 0 and (x % 100 != 0 or x % 400 == 0):
        counter +=1
        print x
        print counter
```

> heres the current result :(

The number of leap years are

```
1900
0
1901
0
1902
0
1903
0
```

Comment: I have updated it! version 2 please refresh again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when needed year occur, the `break` stopped your loop.

```
year = int(raw_input("Input year: "))
end_year = int(raw_input("Input end year:"))

print "The number of leap years are "

counter = 0
temp = []
for x in range(year, end_year+1):
    if x % 4 == 0 and (x % 100 != 0 or x % 400 == 0):
           counter +=1
           temp.append(x)
print('the years are {}'.format(temp))
print('there are {} counts'.format(counter))
```

You also might want to remove brackets in *"the years are []"*, you can do that with

```
print('the years are ', ' '.join(map(str, temp)))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I SPENT 3 HOURS ON THE FIRST ATTEMPT REALIZING IT WAS NOT FRUITFUL. AND THE SECOND ATTEMPT FINALLY IM DONE :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calendar.isleap` to count the number of leap years between given years.

```
from calendar import isleap
year = int(raw_input("Input year: "))
endyear = int(raw_input("Input end year:"))
print "The number of leap years are "
counter = 0
years = []
for x in range(year,endyear+1):
    if isleap(x):
        counter +=1
        print x
        print counter
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a shorter way:

```
from calendar import isleap
years = [ str(x) for x in range(year,endyear+1) if isleap(x)]

print "the years are ", ''.join(elem + " " for elem in years)
print "there are ", len(years), "counts"
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Neat and elegant solution :D